# How do I send telegram bot messages to a group from cron using Botman?

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot, botman

I'm using `BotMan` which is currently using `Laravel Framework 5.7.3`.  I'm new to this so I expect this is a pretty simple question.

I want to send messages to a Telegram chat group on an hourly basis with cron using the following command:

```
 $botman->say('Test message', '-123456789', TelegramDriver::class); // test group -123456789
```

My bot is invoked from the `/var/www/html/mybot/routes/botman.php` file.

How can I invoke this from a script that cron can access?